# Validation form - Error al momento de validar un input

Tags: javascript, html, validación

Tengo el siguiente problema, al momento de validar un file en php, en vez de que salga un popup indicando que falta completar ese input, me vuelve a cargar la pagina y me sale esta URL:

> .html?test=&ok=

Deberia de salirme el cuadro del popup, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```js
$("#ss").validate({
rules: {
test: {
minlength: 3,
required: true
},
ok: {
minlength: 3,
required: true
}
},
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
$.each(this.successList, function(index, value) {
return $(value).popover("hide");
});
return $.each(errorList, function(index, value) {
var _popover;
console.log(value.message);
_popover = $(value.element).popover({
trigger: "manual",
placement: "top",
content: value.message,
template: "<div class=\"popover\"><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"popover-inner\"><div class=\"popover-content\"><p></p></div></div></div>"
});
_popover.data("popover").options.content = value.message;
return $(value.element).popover("show");
});
}
});
```

```css
.popover-content {
border-bottom: 10px solid black;
margin-bottom:-1px
}

.arrow:after {
/*background: black;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">

<form id="ss">
<fieldset>
<legend>Legend</legend>
<label>Label name</label>
<input name="test" type="text" title="okok1" placeholder="Type something…"/>
<input name="ok" type="text" placeholder="Otro input" />
<button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Pero me sale ese error, y no entiendo, si estoy usando HTML, en una web X, Qué podria estar pasando ?

> .html?test=&ok=

Answer (score 0):

Usa la etiqueta `required` de html5 para este por defecto valida si el campo esta completado, también evalúa si es del tipo correcto `email` o `number`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <form id="ss">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>
  <label>Label name</label>
  <input name="test" type="text" title="okok1" required placeholder="Type something…"/>
  <input name="ok" type="text" required placeholder="Otro input" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
  </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora si deseas seguir usando POPOVER y Jquery Validate.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
function enableValidate(){
    var validateSs = $("#ss").validate({
    rules: {
      test: "required",
      ok: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2
      },
    },
    errorContainer: $("#warning, #summary"),
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      let text = error[0].innerText;
      $($(element).parent())[0].setAttribute('data-content',text);
      enablePopover();
      $($(element).parent()).popover('show');
      // opcional add label message
      $(element).parent().append(error);
    },
    messages: {
      test: "Please enter your test",
      ok: {
        required: "Please enter a ok",
        minlength: "Your ok must consist of at least 2 characters"
      }
    }
  });
}

function enablePopover(){
  $(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({'trigger':'manual'})
  })
}
  </script>
</head>
<body>  

  <form id="ss">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Legend</legend>
  <label>Label name</label>
  <div class="form-group" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right"  data-content="Message">
  <input name="test" type="text" title="okok1" required placeholder="Type something…" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="right" data-content="Message">
<input name="ok" type="text" required placeholder="Otro input min 2 length" />
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
  </fieldset>
  </form> 
</body>
<script>
  enableValidate();
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: No olviden revisar la documentacion en https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/ y demos de Jquery Validate en https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/